# notepad++ python 3.5 cmd - wants char not number

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, notepad++

I use Notepad++ and CMD to run Python35-32

I use this code:

```
def main():
    print ("Guess a number between 1 and 100")
    randomNumber = 35
    userGuess = input("your guess: ")

    if userGuess == randomNumber:
       print("you got it")
    else:
       print("that's not it")


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Now if you check random number which is set at 35, it should be understod as a number. When I run stuff in cmd and when I type 35 I get result "That's not it", But if Place "" > "35" in code I get the correct result. My question is, why CMD doesn't recognize a number in my case? Why does it want me to put "" at 35?

Is there settings I need to check with Notepad++ or with CMD?

Comment: `input()` returns `str`, you'll probably want `int(input(...))`

Comment: Thank you, you are very correct it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3 and maybe you didn't catch it.

In Py2 there were `raw_input()` that returned a string and `input()` that returned either an integer or a float.

In Py3 that changed, because Py2 `input()` was actually `eval(raw_input())` and therefore `raw_input()` was removed, leaving `input()` as remaining function that returs a string.

As it was mentioned in the comments, you can use `int(input())` or `float(input())` if you know what number it'll be or leave python to decide with `eval(input())`.